# Construct a solution of Laplace/Poisson problem with a non constant gradient jump

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-functions, poissons-equation

consider the square $[-1,1]^2$ and a ball of radius $R$ entered at the origin $B_R(0)$. The function $u(x,y)=- \frac{\ln(\max(r^2,R^2))}{2}$ solves the Laplace problem $-\Delta u=0$, and the jump of the gradient is constant along $\partial B_R(0)$.

Goal: I'd like to find an easy solution where the **gradient is not constant** along $\partial B_R(0)$. Of course the rhs can be non-zero, as I am just building a manufactured solution. Can $u=- \frac{(x+y)\ln(\max(r^2,R^2))}{2}$ be a good candidate?

Comment: Do you also want $u$ to be continuous?

Comment: Yes, exactly @JackT

Comment: @JackT My candidate solution is continuous, right?

Answer (score 1):

Complex analysis can help here. Say, gluing together on $\partial B_R(0)$ real parts of functions $z$ and $1/z$ inside and outside the circle gives
$$
u(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
x, r\le R,\\
\frac{R^2 x}{r^2}, r> R.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The jump of the gradient along $\partial B_R(0)$ is not constant since in the inner region it is $1$, while from the other part it varies with $r=r(x,y)$, right?

Comment: @bobinthebox Yes.

Comment: @bobinthebox Gradient in the inner region is $(1,0)$ to be precise. Also fixed the gluing.

Comment: Sure, in the inner region is $e_1$, that's okay. The thing was to find a non-constant jump along the the curve :-) Thanks again